# Login.live.com Server not found Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-10, microsoft-graph-api, service-fabric-stateless

I'm using Microsoft Graph API to authenticate users to my web application. For SO, I have registered a test application in [Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com). This portal provide us application id and application secret. I have defined  [redirect URL](http://localhost:8507/UserService/Token) which take Code and return the access token.

```
 public async Task<AuthToken> ExchangeCodeForAccessToken(string code)
    {
        MicrosoftGraphTokenResponse tokenResponse = null;
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var postFormParameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
            {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", _msGraphpParameter.AppId),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", _msGraphpParameter.RedirectUrl),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", code),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", _msGraphpParameter.Scopes)
            };

            if (_msGraphpParameter.AppSecret != null)
            {
                // Secret isn't needed for client apps
                postFormParameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", _msGraphpParameter.AppSecret));
            }

            var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postFormParameters);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", TokenRefreshContentType);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(MsGraphTokenRefreshUrl, formContent);
            string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MicrosoftGraphTokenResponse>(responseString);

        }
        return TransformMSGraphTokenResponseIntoAuthProperties(tokenResponse);
    }
```

My problem is bit weird. I'm able to access the token without any issues which means I have correct setup in place. However, after few calls(2) Graph API return nothing as [login live dot com](https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=a929dd26-243a-4092-b931-a9b3a0120e99&scope=Notes.ReadWrite.All%20Notes.ReadWrite%20User.ReadBasic.All&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8507%2FUserService%2FToken&response_type=code&response_mode=query&display=popup&uaid=3cacdc29d80446c289118071f2bfa449&msproxy=1&issuer=mso&tenant=common&ui_locales=en-US&login_hint=anand.mohan.awasthi%40outlook.com)  server not found.

I have tried cleaning cookies completely, dns cache but it didn't worked however if I restart my laptop and place a call then it seems start working. Still after few calls, Login.live.com server not found.

Here is snapshot[image]

Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't post sensitive/confident data on StackOverflow

Comment: Looks like some weird DNS issue - it's having difficulty resolving the name to an ip address...

Comment: Well, I thought the same and tried to flush the dns cache and renew my ip address but it didn't worked. Strangely I have used CC Cleaner and it worked. I have licensed win 10, VS 2017 and updated Win's defender, not sure who's blocking *.live.com domain.